# Update and Replace database in MySQL with special character '

Tags: mysql, replace, find, special-characters

I have to change `s-Gravenland` into `'s-Gravenland` in my database

I use find and replace,

```
UPDATE Voornamen_2 SET Buurt = REPLACE(Buurt, 's-Gravenland', ''s-Gravenland');
```

This doesn't work obviously, how do I insert the extra `'` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use double single quotes to represent a single quote in a string:

```
UPDATE Voornamen_2
    SET Buurt = REPLACE(Buurt, 's-Gravenland', '''s-Gravenland');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an extra `single quote` char to accept it as part of data.

```
UPDATE Voornamen_2 
   SET Buurt = REPLACE( Buurt, 's-Gravenland', '''s-Gravenland' );
```

Or, you can also escape it to include with the data.

```
UPDATE Voornamen_2 
   SET Buurt = REPLACE( Buurt, 's-Gravenland', '\'s-Gravenland' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query should work:

```
UPDATE Voornamen_2 
SET Buurt = REPLACE(Buurt, "s-Gravenland", "'s-Gravenland");
```